# How to change Toggle button unchecked state drawable Image color?

Tags: android

Que: **How to change color of Toggle button unchecked state drawable Image in dark theme/night mode programatically also without using selector in Android?**

(Basically, I want to change fill color of image which is downloaded from vector assets and using it in toogle button)

I've a toggle button:

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
```

Inside, I sat `android:background="@drawable/favorite"` when you open this XML it will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Vector asset Image: **ic_star_border_black_24dp**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M22,9.24l-7.19,-0.62L12,2 9.19,8.63 2,9.24l5.46,4.73L5.82,21 12,17.27 18.18,21l-1.63,-7.03L22,9.24zM12,15.4l-3.76,2.27 1,-4.28 -3.32,-2.88 4.38,-0.38L12,6.1l1.71,4.04 4.38,0.38 -3.32,2.88 1,4.28L12,15.4z" />
</vector>
```

So first Item(Image) is Red color and second Item (Image: ic_star_border_black_24dp) is black color which is border which is basically star image.

Now, when I do this in my adapter:

```
if (RemindMe.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled) {

            }
```

Inside that condition, I want to change this default black color image (ic_star_border_black_24dp) to white.

How can I achieve this?

Please Note: I checked almost all answers in stack overflow regarding this, but suggestion are related to selector/or take one new white color image, which I don't want to do because already I've 2 image for this simple things..

I tried this, but no effect:

```
    if (RemindMe.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled) {
                    PorterDuffColorFilter porterDuffColorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE,
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp).setColorFilter(port

erDuffColorFilter);
            }
```